# Google Appengine , Django, Haystack and CloudSQL

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-haystack, google-cloud-sql

Does anyone know what haystack backends work on appengine with the cloudsql db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem and did not find any GAE friendly way to use Django Haystack. You may be able to do something with Whoosh as it is pure Python, but I have my doubts.

An alternative is the use of [Django nonrel search](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/nonrel-search).  It does not contain all the features of Haystack and its associated backends, but it may provide what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try a hosted Elastic Search solution, such as searchbox.io. More information on getting it [working with Haystack here](http://dev.searchbox.io/python/).